# Gundo.vimとPythonの関係

Tags: vim

win10上のgvimでGundo.vimを利用したくdein.vimを使ってインストールしましたが

`Gundo requires Vim to be compiled with Python 2.4+`

と出ます。
Pythonは3系をAnacondaからすでにインストール済みですが今回は2系でないとだめでしょうか。
Anacondaをインストールする際PATHを通すにチェックを入れてコマンドプロンプトからでもpythonできるようにしているはずですが…

ちなみに`:echo has('python')`は0です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4):

`python` コマンドではなく、Python が組み込まれた Vim が必要になります。用意する方法は環境によって変わってくるので、調べてみてください。
[ドキュメントによると](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim/blob/master/doc/gundo.txt#L239)、もし Python 3 系が Vim に組み込まれていれば(`:echo has('python3')` が 1 になれば)、以下のようにオプション変数を設定することで動くようです。

```
let g:gundo_prefer_python3 = 1
```

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。https://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/hhhappyyyymoto/35090474.htmlを参考に、gvim.exeと同じフォルダにAnacondaのフォルダからpython3.dllや36.dllを持ってきたもののechoが0のまま変わらないです。
Anaconda以外に別のPythonを入れると干渉しそうなので避けているのですが…

Comment: 更に調べてみましたがWinだとpythonやluaがビルドされたvimを作るのが相当手間そうですね…Cygwinインストールするのは容量でかいので厳しいと言った感じです。

Comment: Win用Python3.6をインストールしてみましたところ:echo has('python3')が1になったのでlet g:gundo_prefer_python3 = 1をvimrcに加えて起動したところ起動してすぐ強制終了するようになりました…

Answer (score 1):

Vimがkaoriya版であれば公式のPython3.5を入れると動くと思います。
Python を使わない https://github.com/mbbill/undotree を使うのも手かと。